# AspNetCore and Angular2, internationalization logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, routes, localization, single-page-application

I am trying to add localization to our application. The problem is, I don't understand how to make it behave the way I want.

I have a 'Home' controller that bootstraps the angular app, and I have a SpaFallback that goes to that home controller. I make a request to localhost, after MVC is done with routing to home, I can see my bootstrapped app - and at this point the routing is now taken over by angular.

How can I add "prefix" route - the language/culture to the MVC? I don't want to change routes on the front end yet, but I want the 'en'/'fr' prefix added?